# Android Studio Error -> "The following SDK component was not installed: extra-google-m2repository"

Tags: android-studio

I have installed Android Studio and when I run it I get this message:

> Android SDK was installed to C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>   Refresh Sources:
>    Fetched Add-ons List successfully
>    Refresh Sources
>   
>   Installing Archives:
>    Preparing to install archives
>    Download interrupted: URL not found.
>    Done. Nothing was installed.
>   **The following SDK component was not installed: extra-google-m2repository**

[image]

I have tried everything in similar posts I found here on stackoverflow, suck us downloading the plugin files of another version, and none worked for me.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I started the sdk-manager manually and  it installed lots of packages. After finishing and restart android-studio it started normally.